# List all Pages Libraries using PowerShell and SPSiteDataQuery?

Tags: 2010, powershell, spsitedataquery

I use foreach in my scripting to make sure I get every web in every site in a specific webapp to, in this case, list (and eventually update) all Pages libraries in the SiteCollection. I've been adviced to take a look at SPSiteDataQuery, which doesn't take as long and use much less resources than my method. The only problem is that I can't seem to get it to work even if I follow blogs:

- [Using powershell to quickly debug SPSiteDataQuery](http://www.entwicklungsgedanken.de/2011/06/07/using-powershell-to-quickly-debug-spsitedataquery/)
- [Using SPSiteDataQuery with Powershell](http://jaclynsaito.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/using-spsitedataquery-with-powershell/)
- [Powershell script to get Site Collection Pages and List Items count using SPSiteDataQuery object](http://demantprasad.wordpress.com/2012/08/14/powershell-script-to-get-site-collection-pages-and-list-items-count-using-spsitedataquery-object/).

I get **no result**, **too many rows**, **Exception calling GetSiteData with 1 argument** and the like, but nothing really useful. So I wonder if its possible to list all Pages libraries in all web in all sites in a specific webapps using SPSiteDataQuery?

This is my current resource heavy script (which actually works):

```
# Add PS Snapin if not loaded
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'} 
if ($snapin -eq $null) 
{    
    Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"    
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"  -EA SilentlyContinue
}

#Iterate all webs and print List URL
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp/"

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
        {
            foreach ($list in $SPWeb.Lists)
            {
                if ($list.Title.Contains("Pages"))
                {
                    $ListURL = $SPWeb.url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url
                    Write-Host $ListURL
                }

                if ($SPWeb -ne $null)
                {
                    $SPWeb.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following PowerShell code lists the pages in all Pages Libraries present in a given site collection. Variation of this can be used to list all pages libraries in a given web application. The main thing to notice here is that `ServerTemplate` of Pages Library in `850`

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://sp2010"
$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteDataQuery
$query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection'>"
$query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' />"
$results = $site.rootweb.GetSiteData($query)
foreach($row in $results.rows)
{
  $listId = $row["ListId"]
  $webId = $row["WebId"]
  $childWeb = $site.OpenWeb([GUID]($webId))
  $pagesList = $childWeb.Lists[[GUID]($listId)];
  $itemUrl = $childWeb.Url + "/" + $pagesList.RootFolder.Url
  Write-Host $itemUrl 
  $childWeb.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Sharepoint pro at all. But I give you this, if it can help you, it'll cool :)

http[dot]//www[dot]sharepointfix[dot]com/2012/06/powershell-script-to-get-site[dot]html

(I cannot post more than 2 links =/. But the first above seems to be the more interesting)

http://wethinkwebecome.blogspot.fr/2011/11/powershell-spsitedataquery-debug.html

And of course the Microsoft's one :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery%28v=office.12%29.aspx

I apologize if it is useless =/

Comment: Thanks for trying. But it didn't work. The first link script is the exact same as my third link only on another page. I wonder who copied who? The last link is describing how to use SPSiteDstaQuery in C#, not PowerShell. The second link looks useful, and I'll try it later tonight. Don't appologize, we're both here to learn!