# PoweShell script to show all pages for a site collection SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

Is there a PowerShell script that would pull up the pages in a site collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below script

```
##If you use SharePoint 2010 PowerShell, this is not required
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c”)

$siteURL = "http://localhost/"
set-variable -option constant -name out -value "C:\temp\PrintAllSitesSubsites.csv"
$spSite = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite] ($siteURL)

if($spSite -ne $null)
{
   "Site Collection : " + $spSite.Url | Out-File $out -Append
   foreach($subWeb in $spSite.AllWebs)
   {
      if($subWeb -ne $null)
      {
         #Print each Subsite
         #Write-Host $subWeb.Url
         "Subsite : " + $subWeb.Name + " - " + $subWeb.Url | Out-File $out -append

         $spListColl = $subweb.Lists
         foreach($eachList in $spListColl)
         {
            if($eachList.Title -eq "Pages")
            {
               $PagesUrl = $subweb.Url + "/"
               foreach($eachPage in $eachList.Items)
               {
                  "Pages : " + $eachPage["Title"] + " - " + $PagesUrl + $eachPage.Url | Out-File $out -append
               }
            }
         }
         $subWeb.Dispose()
      }
      else
      {
         Echo $subWeb "does not exist"
      }
   }
   $spSite.Dispose()
}
else
{
   Echo $siteURL "does not exist, check the site collection url"
}
Echo Finish
```

Read more here:https://tjendarta.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/powershell-to-loop-through-all-sharepoint-sites-and-pages/

For all site collections in a web application then check this http://www.sharepointfix.com/2012/02/powershell-script-to-enumerate-sites.html

Comment: Thanks Waqas - this script seems to work. 

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following PowerShell code to list the pages within all Pages Libraries in a site collection

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://epm/"
$site =new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSiteDataQuery
$query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='SiteCollection'>"
$query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' />"
$results = $site.rootweb.GetSiteData($query)
foreach($row in $results.rows)
{
  $listId = $row["ListId"]
  $webId = $row["WebId"]
  $childWeb = $site.OpenWeb([GUID]($webId))
  $pagesList = $childWeb.Lists[[GUID]($listId)];
  $itemUrl = $childWeb.Url + "/" + $pagesList.RootFolder.Url


  foreach($eachPage in $pagesList.Items)
  {
    "AllPages : " + $eachPage["Title"] + " - " + $PagesUrl + $eachPage.Url

  }

  $childWeb.Dispose()
}
$site.Dispose()
```

**Output**

[image]

For more details check [List all Pages Libraries using PowerShell and SPSiteDataQuery?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71361/list-all-pages-libraries-using-powershell-and-spsitedataquery)

Comment: Qassas- is this script suppose to show the list of pages under a SC? i changed the URL and ran it, no errors but didn't provide the results at all. Where I'm I supposed to find them. I don't see anything on the script specifying an export location.

Comment: you are right, I forget to loop for pages, now it should be working as my mentioned screenshot, hope it helped you :)