# How do you query the "Modified" and "Modified By" headings?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server, query

We're in the process of migrating a bunch of sites and upgrading to SP2013 from SP2010.  We are trying to find a way to see when various sites have been updated.  If they haven't been updated in quite some time, and the business doesn't have a need for the site/resource, then we're not going to migrate and upgrade it.

[image: How to query]

Is there a way to run a report from Central Admin or author a query in TSQL to ascertain this information?

If you have other ideas on how to perform something similar, I'm open to read what you've done, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar recently. The most reliable way to do this is to use a SPSiteDataQuery and search thereby whole Site for all Items. Using a [PowerShell Script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/75706/42495) you can execute this query and retrieve the latest changed Items, Documents, Webs etc. per Site oder per SiteCollection.